# matlab nrrd read gzip error

Tags: java, image, matlab, gzip

I have this problem on my MacOS: I've written a nrrd file (https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48621-nrrdwriter-filename--matrix--pixelspacing--origin--encoding-) using matlab in gzip format (large 512x512x200 file), and now I want to read it using the nrrdread function (https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34653-nrrd-format-file-reader). 
When I do that, this is the error I get:

> Error using gunzip>gunzipwrite (line 227)
>   Unexpected end of input stream when attempting to GUNZIP the file
>   "/private/tmp/tp9eb78b24_4ead_4567_b911_db756a8f8444".
>
> Error in gunzip>gunzipEntries (line 147)
>     names{k} = gunzipwrite(entries(k).file, outputDir, baseName, streamCopier);
>
> Error in gunzip (line 89)
>      names = gunzipEntries(entries, outputDir);
>
> Error in nrrdread>readData (line 156)
>     gunzip(tmpFile)
>
> Error in nrrdread (line 86)
>   data = readData(fid, meta, datatype);

I've read in this post (https://www.nitrc.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=5972&forum_id=4073) that it is a Java problem related to gzip function. Does anyone have any idea regarding how to solve this issue so that I can read my image matrix?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have a link to an example file?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. You can find the file at this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzllnM3z4XEtWHdtN3dQaEVIeTg

Comment: Please help me with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The example file has an ASCII header of 244 bytes, followed by a gzip stream with a missing eight-byte trailer. (The gzip stream starts with 0x1f 0x8b 0x08) The data in the gzip stream can be decompressed, but whoever made the file messed up and didn't properly terminate the gzip stream.

Comment: Ok so do you know how to solve the problem? I've used this function to write the nrrd file: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48621-nrrdwriter-filename--matrix--pixelspacing--origin--encoding-
And this is the call in Matlab: nrrdWriter('CT.nrrd', CT, pixelDimension, origin, 'gzip');
Where pixelDimension is this vector: [0.8066;0.8066;3] and origin is the center on the CT. Do you know how can I change the function in order to make it work or how can I change the CT.nrrd in order to make it work?

Comment: No, I don't have matlab, and it looks like I'd need to to be able to download the linked source code.